# Fastboot FAILED (command write failed (Invalid argument))

Tags: fastboot

When I try to run the following command
"fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin" got the following error on windows 
FAILED (command write failed (Invalid argument))
But the same command works on fine on linux. can anyone help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am running "fastboot flash xxx xxx" commands in script file.I get this error only when I run through script, When I run those commands manually It works fine.Adding 2 sec sleep after each fastboot flash command solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

A android restart helped me after a hour of search the problem